# Error 2027 when trying to use QT's Network Library

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2005

I used the advice from [How can i get content of web-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053099/qt-how-can-i-get-content-of-web-page) to download a page using QT QNetworkAccessManager. Here is the code I have:

Header:

```
class WebAccessor : public QObject{
 Q_OBJECT
public:
 WebAccessor();
 void fetch(const QString &url);
public slots:
 void replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);
private: 
 QNetworkAccessManager *netManager_;
 QString pageData_;  
};
```

Cpp:

```
WebAccessor::WebAccessor(){
 netManager_ = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
 connect(netManager_, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), 
       this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply *)));
}

void WebAccessor::fetch(const QString &url){
 netManager_->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));
}

void WebAccessor::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *pReply){
 QByteArray data = pReply->raedAll();
 pageData_ = QString(data);
}
```

I have included the QtNetworkd4.lib in project's dependencies, but I get the following error:

> error C2027: use of undefined type
>   'QNetworkReply'

Please let me know if I've missed anything... I think that I'm not linking the library properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
 #include <QNetworkReply>
```

Comment: Ohh. Thanks so much for pointing it out! I missed the most obvious problem. All other includes were in place but this one. I guess it threw me off that it still recognized the symbol.
Thanks again! :)