# Getting some values using qt creator on a website with https

Tags: c++, user-interface, network-programming, qt-creator

So I am currently building a small app with QTCreator 5.0. I trying to build an app that allows me to connect to a website (using HTTPS not HTTP). so far I think I was able to get something together, but I am having trouble with this (of course I am sure it has to do with the http & https but I am not entirely sureof how to resolve it).

I get this error:

```
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
```

Here's some code I put up:

```
QString str;
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    connect(m_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
         this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::fetch()
{
    m_manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker")));
}

void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* pReply)
{
    QByteArray data = pReply->readAll();
    QString str(data);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    fetch();
    ui->textBrowser->setText(str);
}
```

I looked at [How can i get content of web-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053099/how-can-i-get-content-of-web-page), and it may be relevant but I am not entire sure of if this even applies to https

Thanks!

Comment: you will need to link against openssl I believe.

Comment: would that be done by importing ?

Comment: I don't know much about qmake, I use cmake and added `find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)` to the CMakeLists.txt and `${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}` to `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ...`

Comment: Sorry I'm still new to this, the qmake? where would that be?

Comment: the project format qtcreator uses.

Comment: So sorry! haha after about an hour of searching I figured that out! I didn't know where to look, forgot about google for that moment, but now when I press the button, I get nothing... Shouldn't i get some text after pressing the button
?

Comment: No, you need to move `ui->textBrowser->setText(str);` to replyFinished

Comment: Great everything works! THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this as an answer :

1. You should link against openssl.
2. You need to move `ui->textBrowser->setText` to the `replyFinished` slot.

Comment: I actually figured out sometime recently that if I add ssleay32 to the debug folder, it actually works. I also realized this is a windows related things, because when i compile it on my Linux computer it works just fine. thanks!

Comment: Wow that was a long time ago! but yeah windows is weird.