# How to read flash content of a webpage?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit, qtwidgets, qtwebengine

I am developing an application using web engine and Qt. I have an URL and I need to read the flash player contents of this web page for our input to transfer it on other. How can I read it (library, class)?

Comment: Have you tried to download content of a webpage? (like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1053134/2707359 ) After it you can parse this page to get information about Flash.

Comment: Hi,
Qt WebEngine does not Interact with QNetworkAccessManager

Some classes of Qt Network such as QAuthenticator were reused for their interface but, unlike Qt WebKit, Qt WebEngine has its own HTTP implementation and can't go through a QNetworkAccessManager.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html#qt-webengine-does-not-interact-with-qnetworkaccessmanager

Comment: Ok, it was just an example "how to download something". Have you downloaded that page another way? If no, why? If yes, can you parse it? If no, why?